# Inconsistencies in tokenizing large English files using Stanford's PTBTokenizer?

Tags: tokenize, stanford-nlp

I have the Stanford PTBTokenizer (included with POS tagger v3.2.0) from the Stanford JavaNLP API that I'm using to try to tokenize a largish (~12M) file (English language text).  Invoking from bash:

```
java -cp ../david/Desktop/quest/lib/stanford-parser.jar \
  edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer -options normalizeAmpersandEntity=true \
  -preserveLines foo.txt >tmp.out
```

I see instances of punctuation not tokenized properly in some places but not others.  E.g., output contains "Center, Radius{4}" and also contains elsewhere "Center , Radius -LCB- 4 -RCB-".  (The former is a bad tokenization; the latter is correct.)

If I isolate the lines that don't get tokenized properly in their own file and invoke the parser on the new file, the output is fine.

Has anybody else run into this?  Is there a way to work around that doesn't involve checking output for bad parses, separating them, and re-tokenizing?

Comment: No, haven't seen this. If it doesn't happen when run on smaller portions of the text, you'd have to suspect that this is a problem with the jflex-produced FSM though. If you can email the whole file or a large enough segment to illustrate the problem, we could try to look into it....

Comment: @Chris: Thank you!  I have sent email to your cs dot stanford account.  Looking forward to any insight you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to the latest version (3.3.0) fixed the comma attachment problem.  There are spurious cases of brackets/braces not being tokenized correctly (mostly because they are [mis-]recognized as emoticons).

Thanks again to Professor Manning & John Bauer for their prompt & thorough help.